# Optional Where Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Given I have a simple join query:

```
$googleAds = TrackingApi::where("company_id",$companyId)
                         ->leftJoin("googleads",function($join) use ($date){

                       $join->on("tracking_api.google_id", "googleads.id")
                            ->where("googleads.created", "<=", $date
                            })
                         ->select(DB::raw('count(googleads.id) as totalAds'))->get();
```

The data parameter its comming from admin dashboard, but its optional parameter.

**Question**: how do I go when `$date` its not given ?

**Clarification:** when `$date` not given just perform the query normally.

Comment: Vanilla PHP is legit, even pure SQL when too much "abstraction" gets in the way,

Comment: that is very true statement well done, my question its slightly more specific tho. @ItayMoav-Malimovka

Comment: I was refering to your specific problem. Vanilla PHP + Vanilla SQL would we way more simpler and cleared here to read. :-) just think how "stupidly" simple it is, so it feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `when` method:

```
$googleAds = TrackingApi::where("company_id",$companyId)
     ->leftJoin("googleads",function($join) use ($date){
         $join->on("tracking_api.google_id", "googleads.id")
              ->when($date, function ($query) use ($date) {
                  return $query->where("googleads.created", "<=", $date
              })
     })
     ->select(DB::raw('count(googleads.id) as totalAds'))->get();
```

Comment: hmm interesting, well this will throw a `You have an error in you SQL syntax` since I presume that `when` method execute the closure only when `$date` its provided. Therefore join will not happen, I want the join to be included even when `$date` not provided

Comment: well thats my point. when date not provided then date will not exist

Comment: currently applying your answer. I will provide you a green tick in case it works correctly.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative:

```
$googleAds = TrackingApi::where("company_id", $companyId)
     ->leftJoin("googleads",function($join) use ($date){    
         $join->on("tracking_api.google_id", "=", "googleads.id");
         if (!empty($date)) 
            $join->where("googleads.created", "<=", $date);
      });                
     ->select(DB::raw('count(googleads.id) as totalAds'))
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

@user320487 answer was right but, You can also pass the 2nd parameter in method instead of using 'use'  keyword in closers that would be a more readable & maintainable code.

```
$googleAds =
    TrackingApi::whereCompany_id($companyId)
        ->leftJoin("googleads", function ($join) use ($date) {
            $join->on("tracking_api.google_id", "googleads.id")
                ->when($date, function ($query, $date) {
                    return $query->where("googleads.created", "<=", $date);
                });
        })
        ->select(DB::raw('count(googleads.id) as totalAds'))
        ->get();
```